# Bash Read mouse events for specific amount of time

Tags: bash, x11

I have a script, which is basically like this:

```
while :
do
    sleep 1m

    some_val=$(python "a.py" 2>&1)
    if [ $some_val -ge 1 ]
    then
        #dosomething
    fi
done
```

I want to `#dosomething` whenever `$some_val -ge 1`  and the mouse didn't move or click for the last minute. How can I archive this inside Bash?

Comment: You can use `eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)` to store the current mouse location in $X and $Y. If you just care about how long the user did nothing, you can use `xprintidle`

Comment: @ChristophSommer `xprintidle` did the trick. Keyboard input was not particularly important for me, however, it works like a charm!